# Marking fields as deprecated with graphql shorthand

Tags: graphql

I'm using [GraphQL shorthand](https://github.com/sogko/graphql-schema-language-cheat-sheet/blob/master/graphql-shorthand-notation-cheat-sheet.pdf) to specify the types in a schema, eg

```
type Car {
  id: ID!
  make: String
  model: String
  description: String
}
```

Using this shorthand, is there a way to mark a field as deprecated? Say I wanted to mark description as deprecated. Here's my wild guess on how to do this.

```
type Car {
  id: ID!
  make: String
  model: String
  @deprecated
  description: String
}
```

But no dice. Is field deprecation achievable in GraphQL shorthand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup, you can mark fields as deprecated like this:

```
type Car {
  id: ID!
  make: String
  model: String
  description: String @deprecated(reason: "Field is deprecated!")
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Do I need some special version of the tooling to take advantage of that? I'm using `makeExecutableSchema` from `graphql-tools` to build my schema.




    `var executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
      typeDefs: schema,
      resolvers: resolvers
    });`

Comment: doesn't look like the introspection tool or the graphql intellij plugin is able to pick it up. unsure if anything has changed

Comment: It's documented in the GraphQL spec here: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec--deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can deprecate like this

```
directive @deprecated(
  reason: String = "No longer supported"
) on FIELD_DEFINITION | ENUM_VALUE

type ExampleType {
  newField: String
  oldField: String @deprecated(reason: "Use `newField`.")
}
```

for more info plz refer to apollo server [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/directives/)